# Google APIS return wrong zip code

Tags: google-maps

I try to get the map from Google APIS, my link is:
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=%E3%80%92106-6108%E6%9D%B1%E4%BA%AC%E9%83%BD%E6%B8%AF%E5%8C%BA%E5%85%AD%E6%9C%AC%E6%9C%A8%E5%85%AD%E6%9C%AC%E6%9C%A8%E3%83%92%E3%83%AB%E3%82%BA%E6%A3%AE%E3%82%BF%E3%83%AF%E3%83%BC%EF%BC%98%E9%9A%8E+JP

address = 〒106-6108東京都港区六本木六本木ヒルズ森タワー８階
but the result return "formatted_address" : "Roppongi Hills Mori Tower, 6 Chome-10-1 Roppongi, Minato-ku, Tōkyō-to 106-0032, Japan",

Why I inputed 106-6108, but Google return 106-0032 ?

Please help me, how can I fix that ? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?language=ja&address=%E5%85%AD%E6%9C%AC%E6%9C%A8%E3%83%92%E3%83%AB%E3%82%BA%E6%A3%AE%E3%82%BF%E3%83%AF%E3%83%BC

ummm... I think it is because Google Maps has the wrong info about `六本木ヒルズ森タワー`.

[image]

In this case, consider reporting this problem to Google Maps team:

https://support.google.com/maps/answer/3094088?hl=en